# MySQL group by on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
+---------------------+-------+-----+
|       dateTime      | value |  id |
+---------------------+-------+-----+
| 2013-04-06 06:54:00 |  2.5  |  1  |
| 2013-04-06 06:55:00 |  2.9  |  2  |
| 2013-04-06 06:56:00 |  2.4  |  3  |
| 2013-04-06 06:57:00 |  2.6  |  4  |
| 2013-04-06 06:58:00 |  2.5  |  5  |
| 2013-04-06 06:59:00 |  2.6  |  6  |
| 2013-04-06 06:54:00 |  2.8  |  7  |
| 2013-04-06 06:55:00 |  2.5  |  8  |
| 2013-04-06 06:56:00 |  2.1  |  9  |
+---------------------+-------+-----+
```

I want to apply group by on two columns but query below does not work for me

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY dateTime, value
```

I want distinct values from both columns.
I have tried this one too but this one is not working either

```
SELECT distinct(dateTime),value,id FROM table GROUP BY value
```

I want each column to be unique.
My Desired output is

```
+---------------------+-------+-----+
|       dateTime      | value |  id |
+---------------------+-------+-----+
| 2013-04-06 06:54:00 |  2.5  |  1  |
| 2013-04-06 06:55:00 |  2.9  |  2  |
| 2013-04-06 06:56:00 |  2.4  |  3  |
| 2013-04-06 06:57:00 |  2.6  |  4  |
+---------------------+-------+-----+
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Just to understand, you want both to be unique or you want them to be unique together?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Is it not grouping in the way you expect? Possibly dute to the date time column.

Comment: I want both columns to be unique....

Comment: If we take the first row from your desired output, "2013-04-06 06:54:00" appears twice in your original table but with different values 2.5 and 2.8 do you want both 2.5 and 2.8 to be listed in seperate rows, or do you want one or the other selected somehow?

Comment: There aren't values "2013-04-06 06:59:00" (dateTime) and "2.1", "2.8" (value) in your Desired Output, but they are unique.

Comment: Yes, I don't want those values because I want whole value column unique and whole dateTime column unique....

Comment: is it possible to get 2 unique columns????

Comment: Can you explain what the relationship between the columns in your result is? EG "Value is the lowest value for a given time"

Comment: Its not important.... if I get first occurrence of either `dateTime` or `value` would be fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have unique values in both columns (exclude rows with dateTime or value returned in previous rows) try this query.

```sql
SELECT a.datetime, a.value, a.id FROM test a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
     SELECT 1 FROM test b 
     WHERE b.id < a.id
       AND (a.datetime = b.datetime OR b.value = a.value)
  )
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bbf0/14/0)

Answer (score 0):

When using grouping predicates, the values selected must be either

a) values used to group the results

b) group functions (like `SUM`, `AVG`, `COUNT`..)

do something like

```
SELECT dateTime, value FROM table GROUP BY dateTime, value  (order is not needed to be kept).
```

if you did something like

```
SELECT dateTime, value FROM table GROUP BY value
```

You could end with a table where, to the row with `value = 1`, you would have 3 or 4 `dateTime` values that are different. And that is not a table, so the SQL would be invalid.

Comment: And by the way, if you had checked the SQL console error first, you could have found this information way faster.

Comment: When I use 'group by' on single  column it works fine, but when i use it on two columns it does not apply group on either columns....

Comment: It groups **both** columns, so you will get all the distinct combinations of these two columns. Since there are no rows with repeated `dateTime` and `value`, you will get back the original table.

Comment: yes you are right but I dont want this to happen.... I have stated in my question that I want each column to be unique... it should not return any duplicate dateTime or any duplicate value...

Comment: You cannot do that with just a select. Do 2 queries, one for each column, use the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both columns to be unique, you can use GROUP or DISTINCT:

**DISTINCT**

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT dateTime, value FROM table
```

**GROUP BY**

```
SELECT dateTime, value FROM table GROUP BY dateTime, value
```

Comment: Correction: You can use DISTINCT. GROUP BY is not suited to this purpose.

Comment: Strawberry, these queries have different semantics but will return the same results. There is no difference in that particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking clarity, so let me ask it this way.

For any given date/time, that multiple entries exist, you want the value and ID of the first time it occurred.  Your sample output does not have any for the :58 and :59 minute entry, so I assume you do not want any having only a single record.

```
select
      YT2.dateTime,
      YT2.value,
      YT2.ID
   from
      ( select YT.dateTime, min(YT.id) MinID
           From YourTable YT
           group by YT.dateTime
           having count(*) > 1 ) as PreQuery
      JOIN YourTable YT2
         ON PreQuery.MinID = YT2.ID
        AND PreQuery.dateTime = YT2.dateTime
```

Now, if you wanted it based on the date/time that has the lowest VALUE, the above query would only need to be altered to

```
  ( select YT.dateTime, min(YT.Value) MinValue
```

and

```
     ON PreQuery.MinValue = YT2.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

`SELECT dateTime, max(value) FROM table GROUP BY dateTime`

This will give you one row for each different dateTime with the maximum value for that group of dateTime. You can use alternatives to max() such as min() or sum().

Without knowing precisely what you are trying to achieve, it is hard to give a more precise answer.